# NetTopologySuite said that geometry is not valid, but Sql Server said that it's valid

Tags: c#, nettopologysuite

I have polygon:

```
polygon((0 0, 1 0.1, 1 1, 0.5 1, 0.5 1.5, 1 1, 1.5 1.5, 1.5 1, 1 1, 1.5 0.5, 1 0.1, 2 0, 2 2,0 2, 0 0))
```

[image]

For sure it's not looks normal, but Sql Server 2017 said that it's valid.
But when i tried to read it with NTE it's say that it is not valid. Here is simple code:

```
var wkt = @"polygon((0 0, 1 0.1, 1 1, 0.5 1, 0.5 1.5, 1 1, 1.5 1.5, 1.5 1, 1 1, 1.5 0.5, 1 0.1, 2 0, 2 2,0 2, 0 0))";
var wktReader2 = new WKTReader();
var initialGeometry = wktReader2.Read(wkt);
var t = initialGeometry.IsValid;
```

I tried to 'play' with PrecisionModels but no result. Any advise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `IsValidOp` explicitly and set `SelfTouchingRingFormingHoleValid = true`:

```
var ivo = new NetTopologySuite.Operation.Valid.IsValidOp(initialGeometry);
ivo.SelfTouchingRingFormingHoleValid = true;
bool t = ivo.IsValid;
```

Your polygon only has one ring defining shell and holes, not seperate. To have it valid in NTS the polygon's WKT would be

```
POLYGON ((0 0, 0 2, 2 2, 2 0, 1 0.1, 0 0), (1 0.1, 1.5 0.5, 1 1, 1 0.1), 
         (1 1, 1.5 1, 1.5 1.5, 1 1), (1 1, 0.5 1.5, 0.5 1, 1 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the "Buffer0" hack, as per https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite/wiki/GettingStarted. I encountered a similar issue this evening, and found this question just as I solved it for my case.

> Note:
> Sometimes you will meet invalid geometries (Geometry.IsValid == false). These will cause issues while further processing them. In most cases you will be able to fix this using the Buffer0 trick:
>
> `geom = geom.Buffer(0);`

```
var wkt = @"polygon((0 0, 1 0.1, 1 1, 0.5 1, 0.5 1.5, 1 1, 1.5 1.5, 1.5 1, 1 1, 1.5 0.5, 1 0.1, 2 0, 2 2,0 2, 0 0))";
var wktReader2 = new NetTopologySuite.IO.WKTReader();
var initialGeometry = wktReader2.Read(wkt);
var t = initialGeometry.IsValid;
_logger.LogInformation(t.ToString());        // False

var t2 = initialGeometry.Buffer(0).IsValid;
_logger.LogInformation(t2.ToString());       // True
```

Comment: Nowadays you should use `NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Utilities.GeometryFixer.Fix(invalidGeometry)` to fix invalid geometries.

Comment: @FObermaier I am getting `GeometryFixer does not exist in the current context` when attempting to fix geometry with the above, despite adding NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Utilities as a dependency.

Comment: @NickyLarson, you need to update to NTS v2.4